# MIPS , erase or turning null Array data

Tags: assembly, mips

How can I change the values of every name and surnames in the arrays ? so when I try to print them in console, they won't output anything, like this:

First Array :

`name1`:

`surname1`:

```
.data



DATA:    .word data1,data2,data3

data1:   .word nome1,cognome1
name1:       .asciiz "john"
surname1:    .asciiz "cena"


data2:    .word nome2,cognome2
name2:       .asciiz "giorno"
surname2:    .asciiz "giovana"


data3:   .word nome3,cognome3
name3:       .asciiz "nikola"
surname3:    .asciiz "tesla"
```

what I'm trying to do is "erase" the data of every array when I run my program so I can choose when to erase them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many different ways, but basically the two major are:

1) the `.asciiz` .. did you check, how it is compiled into bytes itself? I think it's the "zero terminated string", so `.asciiz "AB"` is compiled into three bytes `65, 66, 0`.

Now if you want to display instead of name empty string, make it empty string, i.e. write zero at the first position of the string, thus changing content of the previous byte array to `0, 66, 0`. This will of course damage the data forever.

2) in case you want to keep the original names intact in memory, with your 2-levels deep pointer structure (DATA->data1->string) you can have somewhere empty string like `empty: .asciiz ""`, and modify the pointers in `data1` structure. So from `data1: .word nome1,cognome1` you would modify the content of that memory to `data1: .word empty,empty`.

In either case, you have to identify memory you want to overwrite (i.e. load address of data1 or particular string), and store at that address either zero byte (if you are overwriting strings), or address of empty string (if you are overwriting name pointers).

After that just display the thing as before, new modified memory content will look like the name was erased from human point of view.

BTW, in case you would be doing something with sensitive data, in some security application, it would make sense to overwrite whole name string, ie. to go from `65, 66, 0` to `0, 0, 0`, so after the erase procedure there will be no traces of original names when you dump the memory content (that's third option, how to erase them, very similar to 1), but instead of writing zero at first position you keep writing zeroes as long, as there's non-zero content at the destination).

Comment: in the 1) option  , the way to do this would be something like this:                                                        addi $s0,$zero,0                                                                                              what do you mean by damagin the data forever? however I will just be happy if by doing that and printing the data , it will not display anything.

Comment: hmm... no, I don't know what is $s0 in your example, and neither I'm sure how addi works on mips, but usually add instruction adds something to some register. So I'm just guessing the `addi $s0,$zero,0` is $s0 = $zero + 0? That would load zero into $s0? You want first to load the address of the string into some register, like $s0 .. something like `lw $s0,name1` and then store zero byte at `($s0)`. Then make it a routine, which takes as parameter address of dataN (like `data2`), and does load both name pointers from it, and erase them, so you can use it for erasing any dataN structure.

Comment: Maybe check the memory dump for a while, to better understand what is address of memory, and what is content of memory. That's the difference between working with `$s0` (value in $s0, which may be any number, also address), and `($s0)` (value from memory, at which the $s0 is pointing). So when you want to read/write from/into computer memory, there should be somewhere the `(address)` notation in final instruction. Erasing names in memory requires you to store zeroes into it.

Comment: And check the instruction reference guide, I'm pretty sure you have around some nice cryptic guide explaining all instruction with all possible variants how they can be mixed with registers or memory... reading it few times more, white debugging your code, will solve that "cryptic" feel. After that the ASM is easy...

Comment: yes $s0 is where the adreess is stores, MIPS is quite painfull to learn .

Comment: well, you can store any number into `$s0`... that's just your way to use it, that you put the address there. But that makes whole world difference when you do `($s0)`. If the number in $s0 is not a valid address, that memory reference will be invalid then. So you firstly make sure in debugger that the $s0 contain address pointing where you want it, then you can verify you did load value from that address into other register.. etc. This part of ASM is quite easy after initial steep learning curve, just keep playing around with debugger and re-reading basics, till everything *clicks* together.